# how to reorder columns with only text in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R which looks like this

```
ClientID    Reason_1    Reason_2   Reason_3  Reason_4   Reason_5   Reason_6    Reason_7    Reason_8
 ABC         Trend                  Low                   High       Med    
 XYZ                     High       Low                                          Low
 PQW                                          High        Low                                Med
```

There is no text in every reason column, I want to reorder this to following

```
 ClientID    Reason_1    Reason_2   Reason_3  Reason_4   Reason_5   Reason_6    Reason_7    Reason_8
 ABC         Trend         Low       High       Med    
 XYZ          High         Low       Low
 PQW          High         Low       Med
```

Is there any easy way to this in R other than `ifelse` to check every column to see whether it contains text or not and if not then copy the other columns text into that column.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason you want it in this format rather than as 3 columns? ClientID, Reason, Reason #? That seems a much more natural format for this data, and it's much easier to group and order it (much faster too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by looping over the rows using `apply` with `MARGIN = 1` to select only the non-empty elements, then the empty elements, concatenate it together, transpose and assign it back to the original dataset

```
df1[] <- t(apply(df1, 1, FUN = function(x) c(x[x!=""], x[x==""])))
df1 
#    ClientID Reason_1 Reason_2 Reason_3 Reason_4 Reason_5 Reason_6 Reason_7
#1      ABC    Trend      Low     High      Med                           
#2      XYZ     High      Low      Low                                    
#3      PQW     High      Low      Med                                    
#     Reason_8
#1         
#2         
#3
```

If the blanks are `NA` then use `is.na` instead of `==` and `!=`

```
df1[] <- t(apply(df1, 1, FUN = function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)])))
```

---

Or another option is to `paste` the elements by row and then read it with `read.table` and `fill = TRUE`

```
df2 <- read.table(text=do.call(paste, df1), header=FALSE, 
                  na.strings = "", col.names = names(df1), fill = TRUE)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ClientID = c("ABC", "XYZ", "PQW"), Reason_1 = c("Trend", 
 "", ""), Reason_2 = c("", "High", ""), Reason_3 = c("Low", "Low", 
 ""), Reason_4 = c("", "", "High"), Reason_5 = c("High", "", "Low"
 ), Reason_6 = c("Med", "", ""), Reason_7 = c("", "Low", ""), 
Reason_8 = c("", "", "Med")), .Names = c("ClientID", "Reason_1", 
"Reason_2", "Reason_3", "Reason_4", "Reason_5", "Reason_6", "Reason_7", 
"Reason_8"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```